# npm ci fails on CircleCI with "no such file or directory" for symlinked modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, circleci, multi-module

I'm having a super weird issue with NPM on CircleCI. I have a multi-module project (not using Lerna), with the following modules and respective "internal" dependencies:

- **A:** No internal dependencies
- **B:** Depends on A
- **C:** Depends on both A and B

Internal dependencies are declared using [local paths](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths), e.g.

```
// ~/project/C/package.json
{
  "name": "C",
  "dependencies": {
    "B": "file:../B",
    "A": "file:../A"
  }
}
```

This results in symlinks being created inside `node_modules` in each package which point to the corresponding modules:

- In `~/project/C/node_modules` there's:

  - a symlink `B` which points to `~/project/B/`
  - a symlink `A` which points to `~/project/A/`
- In `~/project/B/node_modules` there's:

  - a symlink `A` which points to `~/project/A/`

In CircleCI, I install each module in order of *A -> B -> C* using `npm ci`. Both A and B complete successfully, and the symlink inside of B's `node_modules` directory successfully points at A. However, when C installs, it fails with the following error:

```
npm ERR! path /home/circleci/project/C/node_modules/B/node_modules/A/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/circleci/project/C/node_modules/B/node_modules/A/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/circleci/.npm/_logs/2019-09-06T14_35_50_141Z-debug.log
Exited with code 254
```

After some investigation I have found that running `npm ci` for module C results in the successful creation of the two symlinks for modules A and B. However, inside `~/project/B/node_modules` the symlink to A is still present but it now appears to be broken (it's coloured red instead of light blue). Unfortunately, the logs don't seem to give any insight into the issue and just repeat the above error (with a little extra verbosity).

I'm able to run this locally (on Windows/Git Bash) without any issues, using the same versions of Node (10.15.1) and NPM (6.4.1).

Has anyone ever experienced anything like this or know how to fix it?

---

#### Steps to reproduce:

```
mkdir test && cd test
mkdir A && cd A && npm init -y && cd ..
mkdir B && cd B && npm init -y && npm install A@file:../A && rm -rf node_modules && cd ..
mkdir C && cd C && npm init -y && npm install B@file:../B A@file:../A && rm -rf node_modules && cd ..
cd A && npm ci && cd ..
cd B && npm ci && cd ..
cd C && npm ci && cd ..
```

Comment: They say here that Circleci seems to not preserve symlinks. It seems they are a few more google entrances https://discuss.circleci.com/t/2-0-persist-to-workspace-does-not-preserve-symlinks/14338/11. They reccomend to `npm install` and activate cache O_o  I hope u solve it in another way.

Comment: All of this was happening within a single job unfortunately and I was able to reproduce the issue on an Ubuntu image locally using docker. Therefore I don't think it's CircleCI with the problem, but that is super useful to know, thanks! I ended up finding bug reports on npm detailing similar issues with symlinks for nested dependencies so I think the issue is there. In the end, I switched to use [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) to get around the problem, but unfortunately I think the issue still persists :(